# Protractor, AngularJS, Parse -- Protractor does not wait for Angular to resolve

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-routing

I am new to Protractor and AngularJS. I'm using Parse on the back end. Trying to do a very simple test:

```
describe('Test', function () {

beforeEach(function () {
  browser.get('index.html#/example')
});

it('should have a button', function () {

   expect(element(by.css('#test321')).isElementPresent()).toBe(true); //fails 

}); ...
```

The test fails. The element is in template.html:

```
 ...
<body>
    <button id="test321">stuff</button>
...
```

It is loaded by angular-route. This route also loads data from back end:

```
...
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/example', {
                templateUrl: 'template.html',
                controller: 'templateCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    data: 'dataService' //Data is loaded from Parse. This line causes the problem
                }...
```

The problem is caused by the "data:" line above. If I take that line out, or have it return static result it works fine. Also if I move this element index.html it works as well.

This seems like a timing issue. However according to the documentation protractor (or specifically isElementPresent) waits for all resolutions before locating elements.

I'm stomped. Many thanks for any help.

Update: According to [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/789) this was solved in Protractor 1.2, but I'm on 1.4. Very strange.

Comment: So far the only temporary solution I found (inspired by aricearice) is to insert an explicit wait. Here's one way that seems to work:

`browser.wait(function () {
        return $('#addReferringButton').then(function (element) {
            return true;
        }, function(error) {
            return false;
        });
    }, 5000);
`

Answer (score 6):

Since it's a timing issue, a workaround can be to wait for the element to be present before you assert that it's present:

```
describe('Test', function () {

beforeEach(function () {
  browser.get('index.html#/example')
});

it('should have a button', function () {
   browser.wait(function() {
       return $('#test321').isPresent(); // keeps waiting until this statement resolves to true
   }, timeToWaitInMilliseconds, 'message to log to console if element is not present after that time');
   expect($('#test321').isPresent()).toBe(true);  

}); ...
```

Comment: Thank you much, this does work. It is, however, strange that it needs so much handholding and doesn't just wait for Angular to "settle", as they put in their docs. This may have to do with the fact that I'm not using $http to get data (I use Parse JS SDK) -- that's the only thing I can think of. I went as far as to start on Parse mock, however in the interim I will use your solution.

Comment: On further inspection, this does not seem to work consistently. $('#test321').isPresent() returns a promise as opposed to a boolean, so it falls through right away. Somehow calling that works some times (possibly by introducing a delay), but not consistently.

Comment: Here's a fix: 

`browser.wait(function () {
        return $('#addReferringButton').then(function (element) {
            return true;
        }, function(error) {
            return false;
        });
    }, 5000);
`

Comment: This is very helpful, I could get the first solution to work, but not this last version using the promise. Are the tests/expectations intended to go in the body of the 'then' function? I assumed they were going to replace 'return true'  e.g.:    browser.wait(function () { return $('#addReferringButton').then(function (element) { expect(element).isPresent();  }, function(error) { return false; }); }, 5000);

Comment: `browser.wait` waits for the function passed in to return a value of `true`, so that function passed in should return a Boolean, e.g.:
 `element.isPresent()` 
or `element.isDisplayed()` 
or `5 === 5`.

 `expect(element).isPresent();` returns an object, instead of a Boolean.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 2 I use the following in my **protractor.conf.js** file:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
},
useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
isPresent() will return promises,so put your expect code inside the callback function and try to execute. 

Try below code.hope it will work,

it('should have a button', function () {

   $('#test321').isPresent().then(function(result){
                                expect(result).toBe(true);
                                 });
 });
```

Comment: Suresh, while your suggestion is perfectly logical this doesn't work for me for a strange reason. Protractor just doesn't wait as far as I can tell. This may have to do, as I mentioned, with the fact that I'm not using $http to get data (I use Parse JS SDK) -- that's the only thing I can think of.